# Date comparaison

Tags: android, date

I'm getting a date from a Web Service, dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss.
Like this: 10/10/2011 12:00:00

And, I'm trying to verify if this date is before from actual date, but when I can't compare it with a "if".

Code:

```
  private static Date formatDate(String data) throws Exception{
    if (data == null || data.equals("")){
        return null;
    }

    Date date = null;
    try {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(data);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
  }
```

My method that compare:

```
  Date planeDate = null;
  try {
     planeDate = formatDate(date);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Calendar currentcal = Calendar.getInstance();
  currentcal.set(currentcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.SECOND));

  Date current = currentcal.getTime();

      //Always return false
  if(planeDate != null){
      if(planeDate.before(current) || planeDate.equals(current)){
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to instantiate a calendar object has improper parameter order. And hence is the erroneous result.

Correct signature of `set` method is this:
[***`public final void set(int year, int month, int date, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)`***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Your code for set method has parameters in different order as follows:

```
currentcal.set(currentcal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                 currentcal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Hence, your calendar instance actually returns a date object as follows:

```
Mon Jan 02 18:50:36 GMT+05:30 8
```

Which should actually be something near by

```
Mon Jul 02 18:50:56 GMT+05:30 2012
```

Change `set` method input as follows and then compare the dates. Then it should be working.

```
currentcal.set(
    currentcal.get( Calendar.YEAR ),
    currentcal.get( Calendar.MONTH ),
    currentcal.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ),
    currentcal.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ),
    currentcal.get( Calendar.MINUTE ),
    currentcal.get( Calendar.SECOND )
);
```